# C# Regex that captures a percentage in a named group

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex pattern:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%
```

Which works really well to match percentages. Now what I need is to be able to get the numerical value of this in a group.

I have tried the following:

```
(?<percentage>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%   
(?<percentage>-?\d+(\.\d+)?)%  
(?<percentage>(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))%   
(?<percentage>(-?\d+(\.\d+)?))%
```

None of them work and I only get the integer part of the percentile.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: why not post some of your data?

Comment: So whats wrong with `match.Groups["percentage"].Value` ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex is:

`(?<percentage>-?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*))%`

Comment: what the hell is `5.` percent lol

Comment: I'ts better. +1 I like to use `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

Comment: Doesn't account for a space between the value and the % character, but definitely the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following examples and they all seemed to work (using the first regex that you tried):

```
Regex.Match("12%", @"(?<percentage>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%").Groups["percentage"].Value 
// 12

Regex.Match("12.345%", @"(?<percentage>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%").Groups["percentage"].Value
// 12.345

Regex.Match("-12.345%", @"(?<percentage>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%").Groups["percentage"].Value
// -12.345
```

You might note the use of the "@" in front of the regular expression string - maybe that is the issue you are having.

Comment: none of these can capture `.33`% or `.50`%

Comment: If you want to capture a percentage without the leading 0, you could use this regex: @"(?<percentage>-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)%" (Just change the \d+ to \d*). (And sorry I see that's exactly what you answered below :) I'm just not really sure what the asker's actual issue was...